# Multidimensional array loop php

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

New to programming so please explain as simply as possible.  I have an array as $inputs.  That array has rows as row0, row1 and on.  Each row has key value pairs such as name='shay', age='23' and a few other things.  I need to put those values in a database, but I can't figure out how to get to them and the examples I find go right over my head.  I have made a loop with

```
for ($i = 0, $nums = count($inputs); $i < $nums; $i++)
```

But once inside of that loop I am lost as to what comes next.  Please help.

The array looks as follows:

```
    $inputs =array ( 
         'row' => array ( 
                        0 => array ( 'id' => '2869', 'name' => 'shay', 'age' => '23',), 
                        1 => array ( 'id' => '2868', 'name' => 'Tim', 'age' => '30',),
```

What I need to do is go through and do an insert with $name, $age etc. So I created the for loop, but I have no idea what to do inside of it to get the values of name and age etc for each row.  I know how to insert them, it's just getting the values out of the array.

When I use

```
foreach ($inputs as $key => $row)
```

I can then do

```
dd($row['0']);
```

And return the contents of a row that I would then like to put in my query.  I just don't really understand how to go from the dd() to actually accessing the values for each rows in a way that I could insert them.

Comment: Can you update your question to show what the array looks like and what should be the desired outcome ?

Comment: `foreach($inputs['row'] as $k => $v){echo "$k -> $v<br>"}` However trincot's answer shows how to find the key `row` without knowing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can loop over that data like this:

```
foreach($inputs as $key => $row) {
    echo "row $key:\n"; 
    foreach ($row as $person) {
        echo " - " . $person['name'], " is ", $person['age'], " old.\n";
    }
}
```

See it run on [eval.in](https://eval.in/529844)

Output based on the input you provided:

> row row:
>    - shay is 23 old.
>    - Tim is 30 old.

Comment: If you have an unidentified index, then the array is different then you told in your question. Please do `var_export ($input);` and copy the output you get from that in your question. That way we know precisely what your variable looks like.

Comment: Editing question to better explain.

Comment: Your explanation does not help. Please provide the output I asked for. We need to know the exact structure of the $input variable. I have added to my question links to eval.in to show I have used the structure you more-or-less provided in your question.

Comment: Edited again with truncated output of var_export.

Comment: Updated my answer. But your data no longer has key 'row0', like you said before?

Comment: Valid.  I keep working the form trying to find a more usable result array.